# Setting Access-Control-Allow-Origin doesn't work with AJAX/Node.js

Tags: javascript, ajax, node.js

I keep facing the same error over and over again:

```
XMLHttpRequest cannot load http://localhost:3000/form. No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource. Origin 'http://localhost:8000' is therefore not allowed access. The response had HTTP status code 404.
```

I've read countless posts similar to this one and they all pretty much have the same answer, namely to add the following setting: `res.setHeader('Access-Control-Allow-Origin', '*')`.
That's what I've been doing but it still doesn't work.
I gave an angular.js app on localhost:8000 (when a btn is clicked logsth() is called) and my node works on localhost:3000. Here's what they look like:

```
app.controller('Contact', ['$scope', function($scope) {
    $scope.logsth = function(){
        var datas = {'may':'4','june':'17'};
        $.ajax({
          url: 'http://localhost:3000/form',
          method: 'POST',
          crossDomain: true,
          data: datas
        });
    };
}]);
```

And my node:

```
var express = require('express');
var router = express.Router();
var app = express();

app.use(function (req, res, next) {
    res.setHeader('Access-Control-Allow-Origin', '*');
    res.setHeader('Access-Control-Allow-Methods', 'GET, POST, OPTIONS, PUT, PATCH, DELETE');
    res.setHeader('Access-Control-Allow-Headers', 'Content-Type');
    res.setHeader('Access-Control-Allow-Credentials', true);
    next();
});

app.post('/form', function(req, res){
    console.log("e-mail sent");
    res.send('yey');
});

module.exports = router;
```

Not too much code here but for now I'm only looking to get rid of the error.

EDIT: When I use app.use(...) and app.post(...) and go to *localhost:3000/form* I get 404 error. But when I use router.use(...) and router.post(...) at least the link works fine. Also, there is no 'allow-origin' error, but I do get: `POST http://localhost:3000/form 404 (Not Found)`. However, when I go to http://localhost:3000/form it displays the response and console.log. Should I leave it as router instead of app?

Comment: Open your network console. Is an OPTIONS request being sent?

Comment: And if it is, do you see your headers you're expecting?

Comment: all you need is ACAO, the rest is redundant and could cause issues.

Answer (score 1):

Just leave this single line did the trick for me:

```
res.setHeader('Access-Control-Allow-Origin', '*');
```

**Update:**

You can try to install `cors` module [from npm](https://www.npmjs.com/package/cors).

Comment: Hi, I am facing the same problem.Could you please tell me in which file should i add this line?

Comment: Yes @AnandRaj - in a middleware after initializing your app:
`var app = express();

app.use(function (req, res, next) {
    res.setHeader('Access-Control-Allow-Origin', '*');
    next();
});`
Does that work for you?

Comment: No... I have tested that also.... when i run the project on device , it works for me. But its not working on browser

Comment: @AnandRaj - If you still need it, you can install the `cors` npm module:
https://www.npmjs.com/package/cors

Answer (score 0):

The issue is that you're returning a wildcard origin (`*`) *and* trying to pass credentials (`res.setHeader('Access-Control-Allow-Credentials', true);`).  You cannot to both.  If you must use `Access-Control-Allow-Credentials`, then you will need to be explicit about the allowed origins in your `Access-Control-Allow-Origin` header.

So, either remove this:

```
res.setHeader('Access-Control-Allow-Credentials', true);
```

Or change the origins to this:

```
res.setHeader('Access-Control-Allow-Origin', 'http://localhost:3000');
```

Comment: Tried both options but it did not change a thing.

Comment: I think the origin header would need to be set to `http://localhost:8000` in this case since the origin (page in browser) is 8000 and the target server is 3000.

Comment: Thanks, I think so too. Changed it but the error remains.

Comment: @tzolkin, what does the response look like in the Network tab of your dev tools, or an application like [Fiddler](http://www.telerik.com/fiddler)?  You should see the `Access-Control-Allow-Origin` header in the response.

Comment: I'm only getting this row of data: form / POST / 404 not found

Comment: Sounds like that's your problem :).  If you're getting a 404, then your headers are definitely not even getting a chance to be set. @tzolkin